# Stack Class seperating elements

Tags: java, stack, push

Hello everyone im trying to make a code to remove

vowels and consonants when a user types a string

but i seem to fail at the code and i need to use a stack class to do it

Sample Output should be like this and will ignore non alphabet characters

Enter a String : hello1234!@#$

Vowels : eo

Consonant : hll

Final contents : 1234!@#$

can someone fix my code

this is the error I get
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnUfM.jpg)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;
public class PushPop 
{

//I used the push and pop methods

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("Enter a String: ");
        String str = sc.nextLine();
        
        
        Stack<String> String = new Stack();
        
        String.push(str);
        
        String vowels = String.pop();
        vowels = vowels.replace("[aeiou]", "");
            
        String consonants = String.pop();
        consonants = consonants.replace("[qbcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]", "");
        
        System.out.println("Vowels: "+ vowels);
        System.out.print("Consonant: "+ consonants);
        
        //this will print what is left after popping the elements
        System.out.print("Final contents: "+ str);
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors. Your code does not even compile. Please see [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to remove all vowels and consonants form the user's input, a `Stack` is not needed (at least if you use the ready made Java's `Pattern` in some way). In fact, you get the `Exception` because you try to `pop` from the `Stack` twice, while having only `push`ed once. In particular you first `push` the user's input `str`, then `pop` it to the variable `vowels` (so the `Stack` is now empty) and then you `pop` from it again, this time into the variable `consonants`.

---

```
vowels = vowels.replace("[aeiou]", "");
```

According to documentation of `replace` it will replace all **literals** with the second argument. This means that it will replace all `String`s matching the literal `"[aeiou]"` (if it exists as is in the user's input) with the empty `String`. Instead you should use `replaceAll` method which takes a *regex* (ie Regular Expression) as the first argument:

```
str = str.replaceAll("[aeiou]", "");
```

---

The regular expressions you are using seem correct for your problem, although you want to first remove the vowels from the user's input and then from *that* `String` (which is the result of the user's input by removing all vowels) remove also the consonants. So the logic should instead be:

```
String str = sc.nextLine(); //Get user input.
str = str.replaceAll("[aeiou]", ""); //Remove vowels.
str = str.replaceAll("[qbcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]", ""); //Remove consonants.
System.out.println(str); //Print result.
```

which, if you combine the two regexes toghether in a single operation, can be shortened to:

```
String str = sc.nextLine();
str = str.replaceAll("[aeiouqbcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]", "");
System.out.println(str);
```

which, if you realize that these are all alphabet letters, can be shortened even further with:

```
str = str.replaceAll("[a-z]", "");
```

and if you also want both upper and lower case letters, then you can do:

```
str = str.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z]", "");
```

which is equivalent to:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\p{Alpha}", "");
```

All those examples can be made clear for someone if they read the documentation on how a Java [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) is constructed, so it may help to take a look there, if you didn't already know it.

---

> i need to use a stack class to do it

Can you please explain what is the desired behaviour, and how a `Stack` *needs* to be used? Because it seems like you just want to remove all alphabet letters. Are you required to *not* use regexes for this?

Comment: I was reading my teachers module about Stack and under activities it says to make a program that prints out like that. So I thought we need to use some Stack classes and methods but I was wondering too, do I even need to use a Stack method? I could just another class ill try to make another